# chrome.bookmarks API useless?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

Reading the API docs for the bookmarks API I found amazing things APIs removing, creating, updating bookmarks BUT then I came across a NOTE in the docs which says:

> Note: You cannot use this API to add or remove entries in the root folder. You also cannot rename, move, or remove the special "Bookmarks Bar" and "Other Bookmarks" folders.

[API DOCS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks)

I tested this out immediately in my extension and I was shocked that it didn't work, it says.

> > index.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: Can't modify the root bookmark folders.

I ask myself why giving this API out when we are not allowed to use it inside our extensions, what is the reason behind this, Is there any workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> It means 3 bookmarks nodes are special and can not be modified: "Bookmarks bar","Other bookmarks" and the invisible tree root; While you can do whatever you want to their children.

Bookmarks are stored in tree structure, each node represent a folder or a bookmark.

Go to [chrome://bookmarks/](http://chrome://bookmarks/)

You can see ***Bookmarks bar*** and ***Other bookmarks***. These two folders are the untouchable 'special' folder. And their parent node, which is not visible to user, is not modifiable also, but you can access it by api.